# Sending Events to OBS Studio Brwoser Source

Tags: javascript, streaming

Do you know, how I can send Javasccript Events like a Toast to my OBS Browser Source?

Somehow always the cache must be cleared. Here my try:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-toast-plugin/1.3.2/jquery.toast.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-toast-plugin/1.3.2/jquery.toast.css">

  <script>
    function test() {
      $.toast({
        text : "Hallo",
        hideAfter : 5000
      });
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="test()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I Click the Button "Click me" it shows me always a Toast. But when i include this HTML to my OBS browser Source it only works when I always clear the Cache in the Browsersource.

I know this is not a hot topic in here, but I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks and Greetings!